# vert.x 3 core eventbus examples not receiving events

Tags: java, vert.x

I could not get any of the `vert.x` event bus examples working. The sender sends out messages to the event bus, but the receiver does not receives them.

For example, the simple point to point event bus examples:

- [Receiver](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/eventbus/pointtopoint/Receiver.java)
- [Sender](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/eventbus/pointtopoint/Sender.java)

The sender response as follows:

```
vertx run Sender.java 

Succeeded in deploying verticle 
No reply
No reply
No reply
No reply
No reply
No reply
No reply
```

The Receiver as follows

```
vertx run Receiver.java 

Receiver ready!
Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

Answer (score 2):

These examples won't work if you don't run Vert.x in cluster mode (otherwise the nodes have no knowledge of each other).

```
vertx run -cluster Receiver.java
```

then

```
vertx run -cluster Sender.java
```

Comment: Thanks. Cluster option worked on windows this morning. It did not work on Fedora last night when I tried before posting this request. Will try again tonight. Thanks much

Comment: Hi I tried the vertx run -cluster xxx.java in Fedora, did not work, getting No reply. The same code worked on Windows, Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm on Fedora as well and it runs fine for me... Perhaps a networking setup issue. You could try to force the host with `--cluster-host=localhost`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and ...hoist=127.0.0.1. Did not work either.

Comment: OK. Can you follow-up on the Vert.x user group? Please run the examples from an IDE and post logs. Thanks